# How to autoload a third party library in an extbase 6.2 extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am trying to embed a third party library in a custom extbase extension on TYPO3 6.2, to be able to authenticate to dropbox.

https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk

As the library is supposed to be installed via composer, I did this locally and uploaded the generated filed to the server. I now have the following additional directories:

```
ext:myext
+Classes
  +vendor
    +composer
    +guzzlehttp
    +kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/src/Dropbox
```

The namespace for the dropbox library is `Kunnu\Dropbox`, the main Class is `Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp`;

I expected automatic discovery of that namespace, as it's located in `Classes`. 
So I embedded it in my Controller as such (also tried DI, same effect)

```
   namespace STUBR\Myext\Controller;
   use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;
```

And later on in the class `$app = new \DropboxApp("client_id", "client_secret");`

The Result:

> Could not analyse class:Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp maybe not loaded or no autoloader?

Next try; I followed http://insight.helhum.io/post/130876393595/how-to-configure-class-loading-for-extensions-in (which is for TYPO3 7.x, but makes references to 6.x too) and tried the two following variants in `ext_emconf.php`:

```
'autoload' => array(
  'psr-4' => array('Kunnu\\Dropbox\\' => 'Classes')
),
```

or

```
'autoload' =>
array(
  'classmap' => array('Classes')
),
```

Same (non-)effect.

I don't think I have to go down the road of adding an `ext_autoload.php`, as everything *is* namespaced, right?
So I guess I'm doing something completely wrong here. Maybe I shouldn't include the library in classes, but create some kind of separate wrapper extension that's a dependency for my extension?

What is the right approach?

Comment: From a quick glance: The files for the dropbox namespaces are not directly in "Classes" but in sub-folders. Try adding the path to the folder where the dropbox namespace starts to your autoload definition (so probably something like Classes/vendor/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/src/Dropbox)

Comment: Thanks! That didn't help yet. What worked half the way was moving everything  to a separate extension and placing the files directly in `Classes`. But, alas, there are many dependencies that have been installed by composer as well (GuzzleHttp, Psr). In `vendor/composer', there's an autoloader created by composer. If I could run that, I guess I'd have all the classes I need. But I got the Impression the TYPO3 API prohibits that. Do you have an idea how (IF!) to run the composer autoloader?

Comment: You could try to simply include the autoload.php from composer in your extension (like really use require_once vendor/autoload.php). Other than that I don't really have an idea from the top of my head. Another way is potentially described here: http://insight.helhum.io/post/148112375750/how-to-use-php-libraries-in-legacy-extensions

Comment: sounds promising! I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Wonderful! That approach worked. Thanks again! I did the whole phar archiving, maybe even already the use of `ExtensionManagementUtility` to load the autoloader would have been sufficient.